# Why there is another application called Leaks installed on the Android device when I use ZXing Bar code Library ?

Tags: android, zxing

I have an application that uses ZXing Barcode Scanner library, but when I run the application on the device, there is another additional application installed called "Leaks". Why is this application installed on the device ? When I open it nothing happens ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's an application called leak canary.

```
// For development purposes only
// https://github.com/square/leakcanary
debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.3.1'
releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.3.1'
```

Remove these lines from build.gradle file if you have them.

You should also have this line `LeakCanary.install(this);` in your activity file and you should remove it as well.

Comment: Thanks for your suggetsion.

Comment: Here is the link for the application for more details: https://github.com/square/leakcanary

Answer (score 1):

in your activity file remove the line

```
LeakCanary.install(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

If 'Leaks' app is installing automatically on your phone along with the app you are developing then you don't have to worry you can remove it in a minute. Let's understand what 'Leaks' app does and how to remove it.

**What is Leaks?**
'Leaks' is nothing but a developer tool or a memory leak detection library for Android phones. Developers use it to check or detect any memory leaks and reduce crashes related to OutOfMemory Error. In this case, you can call it an Opal Travel developer extension that has been added by the LeakCanary library.

**How to remove?**

Remove this line from build.gradle(app) file
'debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.9.1'

or you may have these lines

debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.3.1'
releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.3.1'