# App is generating leaks

Tags: android, memory-leaks, zxing

I am trying to integrate ZXing scanner library with my app when I am installing an app it's generating leaks as shown in the image what are those leaks? how to resolve it?  [image: zxing leaks]

Comment: have a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/32867511/5324829